# how to display success message after response.end(); and clear all controls on pagein c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used a method for downloading an Excel file in asp.net using C# ,here I want to display a message of success after the was file generated. i have some controls like textbox on same page and all work done on **button_click** event not **page_load** event , i also want to **clear all control** when process is complete

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + context.Request.QueryString["FileName"] + "");
strPath.Length.ToString());
context.Response.ContentType = "application/text";
context.Response.WriteFile(strPath);
context.Response.End();
```

Comment: add a message where? how?

Comment: I assume that you are using asp.net web forms, not asp.net mvc. Correct?

Comment: what's the problem adding `lblmsg.text = "Report generated successfully";` at the end of this code?

Comment: i am using simple asp.net , i have datatable , i am writing excel using datatable with the help of c#.

Comment: every thing ok but i just want to show msg like "process is complete" in label

Comment: @John Wu, i have some controls like textbox on same page and all work done on button click event  not page load event , i also want to clear all conrol when process is complete .

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a message into the label from code behind in your case because of 2 things.

First, doing something after `Response.End()` won't work, because... the response has ended. So every piece of code after that won't be executed.

Second, you are downloading a file with that snippet. That is the data that is being send to the browser, not a html page, so no changes can be made to the UI.

If you really want to display a message you will have to use javascript / jQuery.

Comment: I want to clear all control when process is complete.